# Docusaurus V2 not automatically use swizzled component

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

I've create basic documentation website with Docusaurus V2 and I want to change layout of my site.

So I run `npm run swizzle @docusaurus/theme-classic layout -- --danger` which copy layout js and css file to the directory.

However, I need to change `import Layout from '@theme/Layout';` to `import Layout from '../theme/Layout';` in `index.js` by myself to make it works (but I still can't figure how to make it works in other page).

In [Docusaurus document](https://docusaurus.io/docs/cli#docusaurus-swizzle-sitedir), it's claimed that

> Docusaurus will use it instead of the one provided from the theme

Am I missing something to make Docusaurus use it automatically?